# OpenFilesHandler no longer works in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I have a Java Webstart application that has a file association in it. It used to be able to open files by double-clicking on it in Mac OS X via the deprecated API. That no longer works, so I upgraded my code to the new non-deprecated API but that doesn't work either!

Here is my code:

```
Application application = Application.getApplication();
application.setOpenFileHandler(new OpenFilesHandler() {
   public void openFiles(OpenFilesEvent e) {
      System.out.println("OpenFileHandler()");
   }
});

application.setAboutHandler(new AboutHandler() {
   public void handleAbout(AboutEvent e) {
      System.out.println("AboutHandler()");
   }
});
```

When I run my application with the above code, I can receive "AboutHandler()" prints fine, but I can never receive "OpenFileHandler()" prints. When I double-click on a file, Mac OS X brings my application to front, but it does not send any OpenFilesEvent events to it.

I'm using Java 7 update 55 on Mac OS X 10.9.2

Could anyone get OpenFileHandler to work in Java 7?
Am I doing something wrong?
Is this a Java bug?

Comment: OT(?) Given this is a JWS app., have you tried using (as an alternative) the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) of the JNLP API?

Comment: Thanks for reply Andrew. IntegrationService does not have any useful feature for this problem. The only thing relevant there is requestAssociation() method but I know that association is already fine because the first time I double-click on the file .xyz, OSX will correctly start my application and pass the .xyz file as args[] to my main method. But if my application is already running, double-clicking on .xyz file does nothing except it brings my application to front.

Comment: If you have Mac OS X and like to try it yourself try my webstart application here: http://www.runiter.com/math-calculator/online.htm

Comment: *"IntegrationService does not have any useful feature for this problem"* Really? It seemed to have everything needed when I last ran examples of it. *"If you have Mac OS X"*  No, I don't.

Comment: Yes it's a good service and I was already using it to recreate desktop shortcut icons when needed. However it does not address this problem with OpenFilesHandler problem in Mac. This problem seem to be a bug in JVM which opens webstart application successfully but fails to pass the filename to OpenFilesHandler. If so, I like someone else to confirm it so that I go ahead and file a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: *"to recreate desktop shortcut icons"*  `<head-desk />`  Try using it to register a ***file association***.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the problem is not file association since webstart already seem to be handling file association well, but okay I'll try that too.

Comment: *"..since webstart already seem to be handling file association well,"*  What the ..what?  I thought the file association was the *core* of the problem.  Don't you want (and not get) 'double click file to open in app.'?

Comment: Double-click does open my app, but my app doesn't receive the filename. So my app doesn't know which file to open, or even that a file was in fact double-clicked.

Comment: So that's still the case when using the JNLP API services, as opposed to the OS X specific API?  Implement logging to check that a new version of the app. is running.

Comment: As I expected IntegrationService didn't work. I called IntegrationService.requestAssociation() which return "true" (I println the result). It popped up a dialog box in Mac OS X asking that "File association MIME already exists. Are you sure you want to replace it?" I said yes. It returned true then. But double-clicking on the file just activates my app without receiving the filename.

Comment: result = integrationService.requestAssociation("application/smart-math-calculator", new String[] {".smc"});

Comment: That's bad news.  Can you raise a bug report for that?  Oracle might care enough about their own API to fix it.

Comment: I will try. I filed other bug reports with Oracle before but it seems they way they decide which bugs to approve is random. I wonder if they even look at these bug reports.

Comment: Though I am surprised that no-one else is talking about this problem. Fille association should be a popular feature. Makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: *"..it seems they way they decide which bugs to approve is random."*  I understand your frustration.  Having said that.. *"I wonder if they even look at these bug reports"* ..I have also seen bugs in the JNLP API both reported and fixed.

Comment: Do you think this problem could be due to same bug that affected its sister class OpenURIHandler as documented here? http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8015303

Comment: I'm not sure.  That's something I'd put to Oracle in the form of a bug report.  If it has a field for 'related bugs', mention it.  If they close it as a duplicate, that would be a clincher.

Comment: They won't close it as duplicate since this is a totally different class (the bug with that class is already fixed) but it might help them fix it quicker if it's caused by a similar issue. Thanks for all the help. I'll file the bug and will post a link.