# OpenFilesHandler not working anymore under macOS 10.15 and higher

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java Application for macOS with a proprietary file type.
When double-clicking such a proprietary file, the application should open and load the file. If the application is already open, the selected file should be opened in a new application-window.

This used to work and still works on older macOS (e.g. 10.13), on 10.15 however this only works when the application is not open yet. If the application is already open, Finder plays the "*animation for opening a file*", but nothing happens.

I played around a while with old versions, settings in **info.plist**, Launching executables (ApplicationStub) and got following results.

| App Status / OS | macOS 10.13 | macOS 10.15 | macOS 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| App is closed when double-click | opens App and Document | opens App and Document | opens App only |
| App is open when double-click | opens App and Document | nothing | nothing |

The difference between macOS 10.15 and macOS 12 is to be found in the Executable that launches the Java-application. Until 10.15 a non compiled script is accepted, later on it must be compiled (so the two apps are not identical but Java code is unchanged)

When double-clicking on a file, i would expect `public void handleOpenFile(AppEvent.OpenFilesEvent event)` to be called, but it isn't.

Since on macOS 10.15 I get the Application to launch and open the selected Document, I suppose the Settings in **info.plist** are correct and the **OpenFilesHandler** correctly registered.

So I suppose there is something in macOS 10.15 and later that disturbs `com.apple.eawt.OpenFilesHandler`.

Has anybody encountered this problem and found a solution for it? Or any ideas where the problem could be located?

My code is written and executed in Java-8, I develop on macOS 10.15 but have access to older and newer systems.

This is not a duplicate of [OpenFilesHandler no longer works in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23750594/9064287), since at time the other question was written, my Application was still opening smoothly and the OS-Versions that are causing me troubles were far from being released.

I don't think it's related with [Desktop.setOpenFileHandler doesn't work when program isn't running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54081531/9064287) , since I have mostly problems when the application is already running, there it seems that the handler was missing at startup (besides it's using Desktop class)

Comment: Well, I see, someone didn't like the question but did not bother to give a constructive contribution. That's not how it is supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of headaches and try and error, I can luckily provide a solution to my problem.

1. The short version: **I used to have two executables, one calling the other, the other executing the java code.** This lead to my problems described above.
2. The longer version:
   The executable that is registered in Info.plist under `<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>` used to be a one liner whose only purpose was to redirect all output (standard and error) to a local logfile inside the applications *Contents* folder.

   `exec JavaApplicationStub >> "../$USER".log 2>&1`

   JavaApplicationStub was for a long while a compiled executable taking care of loading the correct VM and passing the VM-Options defined in Info.plist. It was then first replaced by the non-compiled [UniversalJavaApplicationStub](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub), later by a compiled version of it (slightly modified in order not to log to syslog). Basically it analizes the entries defined under Java/JavaX and then starts java

   `exec java [VM Options] [Arguments] mainClass` .

   With the advent of macOS 11, I had to compile even my one liner script, which with [shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) is not an issue. My App opened smoothly when clicked on it, but it started to show problems opening files by double-clicking them. Depending on the OS I fed it with different versions of the launch executables, which lead to the different behaviour.

The **solution** was to modify *UniversalJavaApplicationStub* and then recompiling it in order to directly redirect all output to the local logfile, making the sequential call of the two executables unnecessary.

I haven't read anywhere that it is bad practice to have different executables, and for a long while this wasn't a problem either. For some reasons the `AppEvent.OpenFilesEvent` is no longer passed to the Java-App under these circumstances.